# Python strp csv rows example .Show me how you would go about with this 

Tags: python, algorithm, csv

Imagine if you had thousands of rows of this in CSV .

```
maps.google.co.ke   GET /maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Africa&aq=0&sll=1.845384,32.871094&sspn=18.498214,20.786133&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Africa&ll=-8.783195,34.508523&spn=69.476093,83.144531&z=3&output=embed HTTP/1.1 1.29646542461634E+015   168722060   1606370688  ?   ken
```

.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Split the CSV and eliminate text before GET/ and text after HTTP1.1 and reorganize in simple sheet . 

import csv

try:
    dremel = csv.reader(open('dremel-columns.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

except IOError:
    print 'CSV Error'


dremel_list= list(dremel)
dremel_l = []
cw = csv.writer(open("out.txt", "wb"))

#print dremel_list

for l in dremel_list:
    if l[1:-1]:
        l_shout = l[1:-1]
        #print l_shout
        cw.writerow(l_shout)
        #print "".join(l_shout)

        #cw.writerow("".join(l_shout))
```

Comment: Just a mind exercise - practice imagining something specific at least once a day!

Comment: I'm imagining that I'd ask whomever was employing me what they wanted me to do with a csv like that, with thousands of rows.

Comment: This is the Qn? Split the CSV file rows and eliminate text before GET/ and text after HTTP1.1 and reorganize in simple sheet .show me your code version , how you would go about with this ..

Answer (score 1):

i think this code in enough to do the job.

```
import re

pat = re.compile('GET.*?HTTP1.1')

with open('dremel-columns.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open("out.txt", "wb") as g_out:
    g_out.write(u + '\n' for u in pat.finditer(f_in.read()))
```

isn't it ?

EDIT: excuse me, I forgot the '\n'

.

EDIT 2: no, it doesn't do the job

```
g_out.write(u for u in pat.finditer(f_in.read()))
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not generator
```

This one works

```
import re

pat = re.compile('GET.*?HTTP1.1')

with open('dremel-columns.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open("out.txt", "wb") as g_out:
    for u in pat.finditer(f_in.read()):
        g_out.write(u)
```

Or, if the file is big:

```
import re

pat = re.compile('GET.*?HTTP1.1')

with open('dremel-columns.txt', 'rb') as f_in, open("out.txt", "wb") as g_out:
    for line in f_in:
        g_out.write(pat.search(line).group())
```